# Two different types in schema

Tags: mongoose

I have a user schema. One param is for status. Is a string like

```
// Esquema del folder
var UserSchema = new Schema({
        status: {type: String, trim: true},
    });
```

But when user want remove status i think that i can put this in false, in boolean (I don't know that this is the best option, please if you think other best option can tell me)

So, i need support strings and booleans in status.

Other option is put status as "" (empty string) and check with length but i don't know if this is the best option.

How i can make this?

Comment: You can always use [`Mixed`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-mixed-js) datatype, but it's best to avoid it when possible.

Comment: yes, but i hate mixed types :(, some idea more?